# Using footnotebackref with hyperref option "hidelinks"

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

If you use the package `footnotebackref` with `hyperref`'s package option "hidelinks" you will get an option clash error, and the hidelinks option with be disregarded. Is there any way to hidelinks while using package `footnotebackref`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbol=$\uparrow$]{footnotebackref}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is a statement.\footnote{And it is supported by this footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the two packages in the reverse order:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbol=$\uparrow$]{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}

This is a statement.\footnote{And it is supported by this footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image]